# Wceload.exe running infinitely on WinCE

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am using WceLoad.Exe to deploy my application on Windows CE 6.0 device. However, I noticed that some time the Wceload.Exe did not return from Cab Extraction process. Because  of this the other processes who are waiting on exit of WceLoad.exe could not continue their execution. I am passing following arguments to WceLoad.exe during extraction.

WceLoad.exe  /noui /delete 0 /silent \Hard Disk\MyFile.cab

Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: You say **some time** it does not return. How often does it work? How often does it not work? What is different on your device between these two times? I would suggest turning off the "secret" options until you get this working: `wceload.exe \Hard Disk\MyFile.cab`

Comment: All devices are same one and have same OS installed on them. Even I tried executing it by double clicking on it, It worked. But somehow it is not working when I called this from code. Turning of the secret option did not help because our application is AutoLaunch application. So the dialog box from Wceload.exe goes behind to our application screen and this create a confusion whether the application is hang because of that dialog or wceload problem.